# Determine when image finished loading with JavaScript or jQuery:

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

How can I detect with JavaScript or jQuery when an image has finished loading, be it from the server or the browser cache?
I want to load various images in the same `<img/>` tag and detect when the loading of a new images has finished.

Comment: Do you want to do a callback on load, or just detect it? If call back, as the accepted answer, possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100252/javascript-executing-function-after-full-image-load

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
$('img').on('load', function() {
    // do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks Matt. Does that handler fire each time a new src is set for the img tag? (much like a value commit)

Comment: that will not work if the image is in the DOM already when you assign the handler, and the cached version is used..

Comment: The <img/> tag will already be in the DOM when the handler is required.

Comment: No I didn't try, I'll implement it after I am sure it's what I need. :)

Comment: @Gaby: It should work whether cached or not. The more critical issue is making sure you've hooked the event *before* the image has loaded: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832953/jquery-check-when-image-is-loaded/2833076#2833076

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i mean the image you want to load.. not an empty tag. If you put an `src` in the image tag, then if the image is cached the load event fires before you have time to assign it.. example http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/Xdeh4/ (*first image does not fire the load event*), but re-reading the question i see that the OP has specific requirements that do not face this problem, as he is interested in changing the `src` of an existing tag.

Comment: @Gaby: As I said, *"...the more critical issue is making sure you've hooked the event **before** the image has loaded."*

Answer (score 7):

The `onload` document's event will fire only after all the elements, images included, have fully loaded.

The `onload` <img>'s event will fire after the single image have fully loaded.

So you can attach a listener to these events, using jQuery objects or DOM's addEventListener (and IE's attachEvent)

Answer (score 4):

Well, this is quite an old thread I came across yesterday. I'm using backbone.js and require.js and resizing my layout always caused problems with views that contain images.

So, I needed a way to know when the last image has finished loading to resize the layout. All, mentioned solutions above didn't work in my case. After some hours of more investigation I found the ultimate solution that is working:

http://desandro.github.com/imagesloaded/

Hope that helps others as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think this looks a bit cleaner

```
$('img').load(function() {
    // Your img has finished loading!
});
```

Answer (score 3):

For a more thorough image load detection, including images loaded from cache, try this: https://github.com/paulirish/jquery.imgloaded

Answer (score 2):

From a very similar question [Official way to ask jQuery wait for all images to load before executing something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544993/official-way-to-ask-jquery-wait-for-all-images-to-load-before-executing-somethin) and just like Pikrass says:

> With jQuery, you use `$(document).ready()` to execute something when the *DOM* is loaded and `$(window).load()` to execute something when all other things are loaded as well, such as the images.

Here are two examples:

##DOM

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    console.log('DOM ready');
});
```

##Images / Everything Else

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
    console.log('all other things ready');
});
```

You should be able to confirm in your console:

[image: screenshot-with-shadow.png]

Answer (score 0):

Everyone mentioned that the event should be fired before set to the  src.

But if you don't want to worry about it, you can use the `oncomplete` event (will be fired even with cached images) to fire `onload`, like this:

```
$("img").one("load", function() {
  // do stuff
}).each(function() {
  if(this.complete) $(this).load();
});
```

Using jQuery you don't have to worry about backward compatibility (eg: `img.height>0` in `IE`)