# Looking for an alternative to the image onLoad

Tags: javascript, events, onload, dom-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery or JavaScript: Determine when image finished loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494437/jquery-or-javascript-determine-when-image-finished-loading)

The problem is known, but I can't find any simple solution:

```
var img = new Image();

img.onLoad = function() {
  console.log("load");         // this event doesn't fire
};

img.src = "img/domino/21.png";

console.log(img.complete);     // false

setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(img.complete);   // sometimes true, sometimes false
}, 10);
```

I was looking for an implementation of onComplete event, but I can't find anything. Would you help?

Comment: Try [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494437/jquery-or-javascript-determine-when-image-finished-loading)

Comment: `onload`, not `onLoad`; JavaScript is case-sensitive, even if HTML isn't.

Comment: @Riateche - my image isn't in DOM, it's Image object.

Comment: @Phrogz - DAMN IT :D:D:D. I lost an hour because of one letter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The proper spelling of the event handler property is all lowercase `.onload`, not `.onLoad`.

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function() {
  console.log("load");         // works every time
};

img.src = "img/domino/21.png";
```

Javascript is case sensitive so you MUST use the proper case for all object properties.

---

The alternatives besides `.onload` are to use:

```
img.addEventListener("load", function(e) {...});
```

or (in older versions of IE):

```
img.attachEvent("onload", function(e) {...});
```

If you're only using one event handler and you aren't using a cross platform library that already abstracts event handlers for you, then using `.onload` is the simplest.

And, here's a simple cross browser way to add event handlers:

```
// add event cross browser
function addEvent(elem, event, fn) {
    if (elem.addEventListener) {
        elem.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    } else {
        elem.attachEvent("on" + event, function() {
            // set the this pointer same as addEventListener when fn is called
            return(fn.call(elem, window.event));   
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: the question is `Looking for an alternative to the image onLoad`, not `why onLoad is not working`.

Comment: Yes, but I was looking for an alternative, because it wasn't working. Of course thanks for all answers, but this ones solves my problem:).

Comment: @ciembor - OK, I added a couple alternatives.

Comment: Also today I found that webkit needs `img.src = ''` before assigning new src if it was used before.

Comment: your onload doesnt go off probably since the image is in the browser cache.

Comment: @HolgerThiebosch - onload still fires when the image comes from browser cache.

Answer (score 5):

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
    console.log("load");
};
img.src = "img/domino/21.png";
console.log(img.complete);     // false
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(img.complete);   // sometimes true, sometimes false
}, 10);
```

In Chrome,Firefox and Safari

```
var img = new Image();
img.addEventListener('load',function() {
    console.log("load");
});
img.src = "img/domino/21.png";
console.log(img.complete);     // false
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(img.complete);   // sometimes true, sometimes false
}, 10);
```

Or in IE or Opera

```
var img = new Image();
img.attachEvent('onload',function() {
    console.log("load");
});
img.src = "img/domino/21.png";
console.log(img.complete);     // false
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log(img.complete);   // sometimes true, sometimes false
}, 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure your image at `img/domino/21.png` exists? The following code works for me in [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/)'s console.

```
var img = new Image();

var onload = function() {
    console.log('load');
}

img.onload = onload;

img.src = "http://img.gawkerassets.com/img/17m7otdiw6n8fjpg/original.jpg?" + (new Date()).getMilliseconds();
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can use jQuery it can be simple:

```
$('img').load(foo).error(foo);
```

Or with vanilla javascript:

```
img.onload = img.onerror = foo;
```

Comment: you angered the prototype / mootools fanboys when you mentioned jQuery

Comment: I'm guessing the `onLoad` vs. `onload` (but I didn't do it).

Comment: @Derek. Then don't use it. Did I wrote it's the only way?

Comment: I didn't disagree your answer. I am not the one who downvoted you.

Answer (score 0):

```
var img = new Image();

//blah blah...

img.addEventListener("load",function() {
    console.log("Loaded!");
});
```