# Determine when a set of images has finished loading with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image, loading

So, if you can [determine when an image has finished loading with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494437/jquery-or-javascript-determine-when-image-finished-loading), is it exactly the same with multiple images?

Comment: if you use $('img').load(/*FN*/) in this case you /*FN*/ will be executed for each img, not once. Could specify in more detila what do you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it easily :

```
function onloadall(images, callback) {
    var n = 0;
    for (var i=0; i<images.length; i++) {
        if (!images[i].width) {
            n++;
            images[i].onload = function(){
               if (--n==0) callback();
            }
        }
    }
    if (n==0) callback();
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dystroy/Q6eMX/)

Answer (score 1):

Created a `Deferred` object for each image that is being loaded, and store them in an array.

As each image's `.load()` callback is called, `resolve` the associated deferred object and then use `$.when()` to call a final callback only when *all* of the promises have been resolved:

```
function onAllLoaded(imgs, callback) {
    var i, n, a = [];
    for (i = 0, n = imgs.length; i < n; ++i) {
        a[i] = $.Deferred();
        $(imgs[i]).on('load', a[i].resolve); // not using .onload to avoid clashes
    }
    $.when($, a).done(callback);
}
```

Be aware that on some browsers (early IE?) you need to take special measures to ensure that the `.load` callback actually happens.  That's out of scope of this answer.