# Showing spinner until the whole section is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I want to show loading spinner until a section on the page with images fully loads.

I'm using Django, Jquery and Ajax.

The Html is pretty basic, I have two divs as follows:

[image]

On the left side is an table and on the right side is the detail page. I'm trying to show details on user click. When user click on one of the table rows I want to show the corresponding detail page. The `onClick` event with the `ajax` call is as follows:

```
$('.panel-body').on('click', '[data-inspection-row]', function (e) {
    var inspection_id = e.currentTarget.dataset['inspectionId'];
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/master/inspection_details/' + inspection_id + "/",
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#details-loader").removeClass("hidden");
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('#right_side_content').hide().html(result).fadeIn(1000);
            $("#details-loader").addClass("hidden");

        },
        error: function (data) {
            $('#inspection-errors').removeClass('hidden').html(data.responseText);
        }

    })
});
```

The result that I get in `success` function comes from an Django template :

```
{% for picture in data.pictures %}
     <a class="fancybox pad-no thumb" rel="ligthbox" href="{{ picture }}">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ picture }}"/>
     </a>
{% endfor %}
```

I added `beforeSend` function which is shown for a milliseconds but I still have a problem with the photos loading.

When I click on one of the table rows on the left I get screen as follows

[image]

for about 2-3 seconds and after that the details section loads and I get the screen like on the first image.

Any idea how to show an spinner until the whole right side with all photos is loaded?

---

The HTML is as follows:

```
<div class="panel pad-no">
    <div class="panel-body ">
        <div id="left_side" class="col-xl-4 pad-no-lft" style="padding-right: 15px;">
            <!------------ Left side ---------------->
            <div class="panel mar-no bord-no">
                <div id="left_side_content" class="panel-body">

                    <!-------------- Show errors ------------------->
                    <div id="inspection-errors" class="hidden"></div>
                    <!---------------------------------------------->


                    <!------- Show list of all inspections ---------->
                    <div id="inspections-list">
                        <table id="inspections-table" class="table">
                            <thead>
                            {% include "master/inspection_head.html" %}
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="result">
                            {% for inspection in data %}
                                {% include "master/inspection_body.html" %}
                            {% endfor %}
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    -------- End list of all inspections -------->
                </div>
            </div>
            <!------------- End Left side --------------->
        </div>

        <!----------------- Right side -------------------->
        <div id="right_side_container" class="col-xl-8 panel" style="padding: 15px;position: relative;">
            <div id="details-loader" class="hidden spinner"></div>
            <div id="right_side_content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

I changed the details section (django template) and it is now as follows:

```
<div id="details-loader" class="spinner"></div>

<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-body pad-no">
        <div id="inspection-details">
            <div class="wrapper-outter">
                <div class="wrapper-inner" style="margin-left: 0;">
                    {% for picture in data.pictures %}
                        <a class="fancybox pad-no thumb" rel="ligthbox" href="{{ picture }}">
                            <img {% if forloop.last %} id="last-img" {% endif %} class="img-responsive"
                                                       src="{{ picture }}"/>
                        </a>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <div class="prevArrow"><i class="ti-angle-left icon-2x"></i></div>
                <div class="nextArrow"><i class="ti-angle-right icon-2x"></i></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And jquery to check if the last image is loaded is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#details-loader").show();
    $('img').on('load', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        if (id === "last-img") {
           $("#details-loader").hide();
        }
    });
 })
```

Thus with `forloop.last` I add an id `last-img` if it is the last `for` loop iteration and then I check if the loaded image has that id and if it has it then I hide the spinner.

But the issue is the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post the html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4494437/jquery-or-javascript-determine-when-image-finished-loading check here

Comment: You need to load the images using JavaScript, add an `onload` handler to them, then hide the spinner once all images have loaded. You can do this using promises.

Comment: @ChrisG I added an answer with link to that question.

Comment: @Boky Doesn't matter; your question is still a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

1) use `load` event for images in jquery, consider, that `img` elements will be created after `ready` event fired. Use `on` like in accepted answer here: [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

or

2) insert `base64` strings on backend instead of urls for images

Comment: @Boky see updates for 1st option

Answer (score 0):

I found solution on another question here on stackoverflow. Here is the link

[jQuery event for images loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910727/jquery-event-for-images-loaded/9589845)

The library is **imagesLoaded** and here is the link to the github page

https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded

I hope that it will help someone else with the same problem.