# How to hide progress bar after all images are loaded

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, progress-bar

I'm dealing with bootstrap bar preloading images on a page. Things works fine but I don't know how to make a progress bar disappear after all images are loaded. Here is my code:

```
<div class="progress progress-info progress-striped active">
    <div class="bar" id='fabbar' style="width: 20%">0%</div>
</div>
<img src="http://placekitten.com/1000/1000" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/1000x1000" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="http://placebear.com/1000/1000" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1000/1000" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
<img src="http://placedog.com/1000/1000" alt="" width="100" height="100" />
```

**JS**

```
$(function () {
    var n = 0,
        $imgs = $('img'),
        val = 100 / $imgs.length,
        $bar = $('#fabbar');

    $imgs.load(function () {
        n = n + val;
        // for displaying purposes
        $bar.width(n + '%').text(n + '%');
$('#imgLoader').hide();
    });
});
```

Now I've got 2 problems.

1. The whole bar is gone before it being load.
2. Of what function to make a Percent number like 20%, 40%, 100%. Now it's 93.33333333333334%.

Comment: [Reference this here. It appears to be a solid solution to your problem, other than the percentages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832953/jquery-check-when-image-is-loaded)

Answer (score 1):

For your first problem you can use jQuery's `$.Deferred` to allow your function to call another function once it finshes instead of running asynchronously. It can register multiple callbacks into callback queues, invoke callback queues, and relay the success or failure state of any synchronous or asynchronous function.
Your code would look similar to this for example:

```
var FunctionOne = function () {
  // create a deferred object
  var r = $.Deferred();

 // do whatever you want (e.g. ajax/animations other asyc tasks)
 // and call `resolve` on the deferred object, once you're done
 r.resolve();
 // return the deferred object
 return r;
};

// define FunctionTwo as needed
var FunctionTwo = function () {
  $('#imgLoader').hide();
};

// call FunctionOne and use the `done` method
// with `FunctionTwo` as it's parameter
$(function() {
    FunctionOne().done(FunctionTwo);
})
```