# Loading html image description div at specified height before and after image loads

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ok, so I have a page that loads an image onto a div, but it happens after one sec. The image has some description and story related to it that also loads but much faster. In fact the description loads at top of screen, and then "shifts" when the image completes loading. Obviously this is bad. I want such that even if the image hasn't loaded, the description loads exactly where it would be expected to be after the image has loaded.

The structure is:

```
<div image />
<div description />
```

Please help so I can go home for the weekend ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to solve your problem. I suggest you read [this article](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/ways-to-reduce-content-shifting-on-page-load/). There you will find a solution that exactly suits your needs. At least it will reduce image jumping noticeably

Comment: Thanks! The article also did something similar to what I figured out. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can show the description when image is loaded - detect it in this way with jQuery:

```
$("#image").load(function (){
   alert("Image loaded!");
});
```

see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832953/jquery-check-when-image-is-loaded) for deails

Comment: Yes, I was thinking in that route but it turned out to be much simpler to load the description in an absolute sense, where it should finally be. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities (as far as I see):

- Add/display the description as soon as the image is loaded (using JS to watch, when the image is loaded)
- Pre-define the width + height (or aspect ratio) of the image and reserve that space, so the image loads into it and even the text is below it, it will be in the correct position from the beginning

Comment: Yes you are partly right - the description should also be loaded into absolute positioning for it work.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to add style information onto the description tag:

```
style="position: absolute; top: 1000px;"
```

Here the 1000px is the height of the actual image. This will ensure that the description loads at 1000 pixels below the top margin, leaving space for the image to then load after 1 second, **without shifting the description**.

Comment: And I was able to go home as well ;)